# Is there a better way to do callback chaining in javascript?

Tags: javascript, callback

I wrote a callback helper, that lets me group multiple callbacks into one function variable:

```
function chainCallbacks() {
    var callbacks = arguments;
    return function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            if(callbacks[i] != null) {
                callbacks[i].apply(null, arguments);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

this works, but I'm wondering if there are any javascript libraries that provide the same functionality?   or even better, something that simulates the .NET "event" pattern?

```
myEvent+=myCallback;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3249646/139010

Comment: Looking at your solution, they seem to be synchronous (or at least they don't need to wait for each other), so why would you need an approach like this, or a library? You could just pass a function that calls the callbacks.

Comment: @mat ball: i don't think your link is related.... ?!?!

Comment: @silly little me:  this is so i can append a callback, without removing the previously assigned function.   My specific reason is so I can append to the Requirejs.config.callback variable, but i'd think the reason would be self explanatory :(

Comment: I don't see the difference, other than you'd need to cache the original function.

Comment: `myEvent+=myCallback;` syntax works only because you can overwrite default behavior of operators in .NET

Comment: @carlos:  yeah i was wondering if someone made a library to provide similar functionality, like "myEvent.add(function);"  maybe not then.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your chainCallbacks function. You can test below code in JS console (I'm using Chrome -works fine), and check the result.

```
var result = 0;

function a() {
        result += 5;
        console.log(result);
        _next();
}

function b() {
        result += 10;
        console.log(result);
        _next();
}

function c() {
        result += 20;
        console.log(result);
        _next();
}

function chainCallbacks() {

    var _this = this;
    var _counter = 0;
    var _callbacks = arguments;

    var _next = function() {
        _counter++;
        if(_counter < _callbacks.length) {
            _callbacks[_counter].apply(_this);
        }
    };

    _this._next = _next;

    return function() {
        if(_callbacks.length > 0) {
            _callbacks[0].apply(_this);
        }
    };
}

var queue = chainCallbacks(a, b, c);
queue();
```

Idea is simple - you call `_next()` whenever your callback function has finished executing, and you want to jump to another. So you can call `_next()` e.g. after some jQuery animation as well, and this way you will preserve the order of the functions.

Comment: could you please explain why adding the _next() is needed?  I can see it being useful for asynchronous execution,  but adds complexity (the function being called needs to be aware of the chainCallbacks._next functionality)

Comment: Exactly - it's useful in case of asynchronous operations. I thought this is the case, as in other case you can use simple `array` as FIFO queue. Then use `push` method to add new elements, and `shift` to remove and return first element (`pop` to remove and return to behave like simple stack [LIFO]).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace a callback with one that calls the original as well as some others, I'd probably just do something like this:

```
Requirejs.config.callback = function(orig) {
    var fns = [orig, first, second, third];
    return function() {
        fns.forEach(function(fn) { fn.apply(null, this); }, arguments);
    };
}(Requirejs.config.callback);
```

---

But if you're doing this often, I think your solution will be as good as it gets. I don't see need for a library.

```
Requirejs.config.callback = chainCallbacks(Requirejs.config.callback, first, second, third)
```

A library can't do anything to extend language syntax in JavaScript. It's limited to what's available... no operator overloading or anything.