# jQuery/JavaScript - Start one function once another has finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

What is the best way to fire a function once another has finished?

At the moment I have 6 functions that I'm calling on DOM load like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    func1();
    func2();
    func3();
    func4();
    func5();
    func6();
});

function func1(){
    do some stuff
}

function func2(){
    do some stuff
}

function func3(){
    do some stuff
}

function func4(){
    do some stuff
}

function func5(){
    do some stuff
}

function func6(){
    do some stuff
}
```

But I want them to fire one after another. How would I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: **Exactly in the way you did.** They'll be executed once after the other!!! You're not writing parallel code so interpreter will do what you say in the order you write it.

Comment: if the functions does not have any asynchronous operations what you have done is fine

Comment: @Adriano - I thought that, but 3 of the functions pull data from different SharePoint lists using SPServices, while the other three take that data and present it on a page in three different charts using HighCharts. I expected the charts to appear one after another, but they all seem to appear at once. I wanted them to appear one after the other so that the user wasn't sat looking at an empty page for a couple of seconds while they all load.

Comment: Then they're asynchronous. Using promises might be a solution. But if you use an ajax library, chances are that it provides an answer, be it callbacks or promises.

Comment: If you force these to execute synchronously that won't necessarily make the first chart appear faster.  Asynchronous operations are designed to work on functions 2 and 3 while function 1 has idle time.  If you take that away you'll likely just end up with a page that takes 3 times as long to load.  The exception to this is if your operations are bandwidth or processor limited, of course.  Can you explain further why you want them to run synchronously?

Comment: @Nicholas - At the moment, the page loads, then it is blank for a few seconds, before the charts are rendered, while the scripts are doing their thing. I thought it'd be better to render the first chart, then the second, then the third - reducing the time that the user is staring at a blank page wondering if anything's actually happening.

Comment: @Godge I certainly wouldn't dissuade you from giving it a try.  If you do, please stop back and let us know how it goes.  I'm curious how it actually works out.

Comment: @Nicholas - I've tried a few of the things posted here but to no avail. My brain's aching right now so I'll come back to it another time and let you know how I get on.

Thanks to all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `callbacks` like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    func1(func2);
});

function func1(callback){
    do some stuff
    callback('func2');
}

function func2(callback){
    do some stuff
    callback('func3');
}

function func3(callback){
    do some stuff
    callback('func4');
}

function func4(callback){
    do some stuff
    callback('func5');
}

function func5(callback){
    do some stuff
    callback('func6');
}

function func6(callback){
    do some stuff
}
```

Read [callback-functions-javascript](http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/)

You can refer [Is there a better way to do callback chaining in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159706/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-callback-chaining-in-javascript/16160229#16160229) for `chained callbacks`

```
function func1(){
    do some stuff
    _next();
}

function func2(){
    do some stuff
    _next();
}

function func3(){
    do some stuff
    _next();
}

function func4(){
    do some stuff
    _next();
}

function func5(){
    do some stuff
    _next();
}

function func6(){
    do some stuff
    _next();
}
function chainCallbacks() {

    var _this = this;
    var _counter = 0;
    var _callbacks = arguments;

    var _next = function() {
        _counter++;
        if(_counter < _callbacks.length) {
            _callbacks[_counter].apply(_this);
        }
    };

    _this._next = _next;

    return function() {
        if(_callbacks.length > 0) {
            _callbacks[0].apply(_this);
        }
    };
}

var queue = chainCallbacks(func1, func2, func3,func4,func5,func6);
queue();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote it is correct for synchronous code.  However, based on your comment it sounds like you are firing off external requests that run asynchronously.  What happens in this case is that function1 may fire off some code accessing Sharepoint and then will complete the rest of the code in function 1 after that...and then flow right into function2 without waiting to see what happens with the Sharepoint request.

My preferred way of dealing with this would be using callbacks from the asynchronous operations.  Once you pull that data from Sharepoint, for instance, you are going to call some other function (we'll call it Sharepoint_callback1).  Add a call to that function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    func1();
});

function func1(){
    do some stuff that calls Sharepoint, which after complete calls Sharepoint_callback1
}

function func2(){
    do some stuff
}

function Sharepoint_callback1() {
    do some stuff
    func2();
}
```

There are other methods of doing this.  JQuery provides callback handlers for almost of its operations, but it all essentially boils down to the same thing as above.

If I misunderstood the question I apologize; please post additional details and I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a queue function. For queue of functions you can use array:

```
var fn1 = function() {}, 
fn2 = function() {},
MyQ = [];

//add functions to array
MyQ.push(fn1);
MyQ.push(fn2);

//remove and call the first item of an array
(MyQ.shift())();
```

If you want use your function with scope and arguments, you can wrap functions, for example:

```
MyFnWithParam = function(fn, scope, params){
    scope = scope || window;
    params = params || [];
    return function() {fn.apply(scope, params)};
};

var fn1 = MyFnWithParam(fn, this, params),
fn2 = MyFnWithParam(fn, this, params),
MyQ = [];

MyQ.push(fn1);
MyQ.push(fn2);

while (MyQ.length > 0) {
    (MyQ.shift())();   
}
```